# Insert part title in footnote in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, header-footer, parts

I have a presentation made using `beamer`. I would like to have a part title in the footer. I have succeeded in putting the part number with `\thepart`, but haven't been able to put the title. Is this possible and how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the part title using `\insertpart`, so you can redefine the `footline` template to use it. A simple example (the actual redefinition of the template depends on the theme used and the desired result):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}{\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em]{author in head/foot}\insertpart\end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}

\part{Test part one}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\part{Test part two}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]